# kaminari will_pagination infinite scroll doesn't go to the number of the last_page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, infinite-scroll, will-paginate, kaminari

A couple days ago, I asked a question how to display multiple models with will paginate , finally I found a solution in using infinite scroll.
Every things work great but I can't trigger the last_page , when I scroll , all objects are display  but the number of pagination stop to the before last number and I can't know If I m on the last element.

**my infinte_scroll.js looks like  =>**

```
$(document).on('ready Turbolinks:load', function() {
    var isLoading = false;
    if ($('#infinite-scrolling').size() > 0) {
        $(window).on('scroll', function() {
                var more_posts_url = $('#poost .pagination .next_page a').attr('href');

                if (!isLoading && (more_posts_url) && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 60) {
                    isLoading = true;
                    $.getScript(more_posts_url).done(function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
                            isLoading = false;
                        })
                        .fail(function() {
                                isLoading = false;
                            );
                        }
                });
        }
    });
})
```

**my render js looks like =>**
 **

```
$('#feedo').append('<%= j render 'shared/activi', :locals =>{:typer => @typer }%>');
<% if @typer.next_page %>
  $('#actti .pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate @typer,:param_name => 'activo_page',id:'actti' %>');
<%else%>
  $(window).off('scroll');
<% end %>
```

**

**in my feed page =>**

```
<div id="feedo">

  <%= render :partial => 'shared/activi', :locals => { :typer => @typer }%>
  </div>

  <div style="" id="infinite-scrolling">
    <%= will_paginate @typer,:param_name => 'activo_page',id:'actti' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Anyone can help me?